# Top line obscures bottom line in d3js svg chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using d3js to draw a chart which plots two data series as two lines.

However, parts of the *bottom* line (the blue line) are obscured:

[image]

[image]

Hiding either line by adding `display: none` in the browser's devel tools shows both lines fully rendered.

The rendered SVG looks like this (sorry for the picture, hard to copy the text):

[image]

Each path is created by its own D3 function because the vertical scales are different:

```
        var theLineFcnA = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) { return xScaleT(d.t); })
            .y(function (d) { return yScaleA(d.v); });

        var theLineFcnB = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) { return xScaleT(d.t); })
            .y(function (d) { return yScaleB(d.v); });
```

And called like this:

```
        function plotLineA(plotData)
        {
            if (theSVG === null)
                return;

            // plot it
            var theALine = theSVG.select('.lineChart').select("path.lineA");
            theALine.data([plotData]);
            
            theSVG.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis);
            theSVG.select("g.y.axisA").call(yAxisA);
            theSVG.select("path.lineA").attr("d", theLineFcnA);             
        }
```

(there is a similar function for line B)

Any idea on how to fix this?  I've fiddled around with various CSS properties on the line but not sure what else to do.

Many thanks

Comment: From the pictures of the graph it looks like the path has been broke up and that eash path element has the default black fill. Can you somehow set the fill of the path/paths to none?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you set the width of the bottom curve (which should be the first path laid down) to be thicker than the that of the top curve.  Here's an example:

```js
let N = 12;
  let n = 5;
  let cur = 0;
  let pts1 = d3.range(N).map(function (x) {
    let step = 2 * d3.randomInt(0, 2)() - 1;
    cur = cur + step;
    return [x, cur];
  });
  cur = pts1[n - 1][1];
  let pts2 = pts1.slice(0, n);
  pts2 = pts2.concat(
    d3.range(n, N).map(function (x) {
      let step = 2 * d3.randomInt(0, 2)() - 1;
      cur = cur + step;
      return [x, cur];
    })
  );

  let [ymin, ymax] = d3.extent(pts1.concat(pts2).map((d) => d[1]));

  let width = 500;
  let w = d3.min([800, width]);
  let h = 0.625 * w;
  let pad = 20;
  let x_scale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, N])
    .range([pad, w - pad]);
  let y_scale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([ymin, ymax])
    .range([h - pad, pad]);
  let pts_to_path = d3
    .line()
    .x((d) => x_scale(d[0]))
    .y((d) => y_scale(d[1]));

  let svg = d3.select('#container')
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
  svg
    .selectAll("path")
    .data([pts1, pts2])
    .join("path")
    .attr("d", pts_to_path)
    .attr("stroke", (_, i) => d3.schemeCategory10[i])
    .attr("stroke-width", (_, i) => (i == 0 ? 6 : 2))
    .attr("fill", "none")

svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${h / 2})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x_scale));
  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${pad})`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y_scale).ticks(4));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```